# Vuex commit fires too fast

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I have a component with a created method:

```
created() {
    this.initMap();
}
```

The initMap is to initialize Google maps, depending on whether the URL segment corresponds to `'map'` or not like so:

```
initMap() {
    const pathname = location.pathname.replace(/\/+$/, '');
    const segment = pathname.split('/').pop();

    if (segment === 'map') this.showMap();
}
```

The above bit of code has a `ShowMap` method that performs a Vuex commit:

```
showMap() {
    this.$store.commit('showMap');
}
```

This commit however never shows up in my Vue.js devtools(under Vuex).The components watching the Vuex store value that `showMap` is changing also never trigger.

If I do this however:

```
setTimeout(() => {
    this.$store.commit('showMap');
, 100);
```

Everything works exactly as expected.

I tried this because the changes actually happen in my Vue.js devtools, because if I look under `state` I can see updated values.

The Vuex commit seems to fire too fast. Is there anything that can be done about this? Why is this happening in the first place?

I can even put a `console.log()` into the showMap commit and it works but it still does not get picked up in the devtools and without the `setTimeout` all of my watcher still don't properly trigger.

Comment: Is `showMap` mutation just changing a boolean value in the state or is it doing somethinfg more?

Comment: @VamsiKrishna it is simply changing a boolean value.

Comment: My guess is that `$store` is set up in the `created` phase. Try moving your `initMap` call to the `mounted` hook.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this was a while ago I am not 100% sure how I fixed this but I think it was by using `$nextTick` from Vue.js.

By waiting on `nextTick` you ensure that your call stack for DOM updates has been cleared. This prevents DOM updates that might rely on other parts of your DOM from firing too fast.

Obviously this is way more reliable than simply setting a `setTimeout` with a given number of let's say `100` milliseconds from my example because if your DOM does not update in time it might still pass this window.

If `setTimeout` fixed your issue I suggest trying `$nextTick`.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick